# How to add all the single integers in an EditText?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following Layout and I need to add all the single digit integers entered in the EditText when I press the green Button and show it on the TextView at the bottom. I'm kinda lost on this one. Sorry if this has been answered before but I couldn't find an answer looking through here.

An example would be 1234 entered in the EditText and the result being 10.

[my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCOxb.png)

I don't know if using an array or something like that would help. I remember doing this kind of exercise before but I can't quite find it. Maybe it was an array and I assigned each position within with a For inside another For.

```
public class AddingNumbers extends AppCompatActivity {
Button calculate;
TextView result;
EditText numbers;
int array[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addingnumbers;

    calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_calculate);
    result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_result);
    numbers=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_numbers);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You could try parsing the number to Integer and run a whille loop when `(num>0)` and `num = num/10` (iterate over each number) and add num to a flag variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed with something similar to this (just an idea)

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String value = numbers.getText().toString();
        char[] chars = value.toCharArray();
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            int parsedInt = Character.getNumericValue(chars[i]);
            if (parsedInt >= 0) {
                total += parsedInt;
            }
        }
        if (total > 0) {
            result.setText(Integer.toString(total));
        } else {
            result.setText("");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can can filter and convert the individual characters to integers using an `IntStream`, first by filtering that the character is between '0' and '9' and converting by subtracting the character '0'. You can then use the `sum()` function on the `IntStream` to sum the digits.

```
  String input = "There are 3 un1que numbers 1n 4 places here";
  int sum = input.chars()
      .filter(c -> c >= '0' && c <= '9') // remove non-digit characters
      .map(c -> c - '0')                 // convert character to integer
      .sum();                            // sum the individual digits
```

Putting that all together we get:

```
   calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           int sum = numbers.getText().chars()
               .filter(c -> c >= '0' && c <= '9')
               .map(c -> c - '0')
               .sum();
           result.setText(String.valueOf(sum)));
        }
   });
```